# How to fix debugging error 424 object required in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm setting up a registry using Excel VBA, utilizing a command button that will let me add new data into the database. However, I keep getting the error 424 object required, but I do not see any problem with my code.

I have tried changing the Range values and creating empty values.

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim NewPatient As Range
Set wks = Sheet1
Set NewPatient = wks.Range("A65356").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
NewPatient.Offset(0, 0).Value = txtPatientID.Text
NewPatient.Offset(0, 1).Value = txtFirstname.Text
NewPatient.Offset(0, 2).Value = txtLastname.Text
NewPatient.Offset(0, 3).Value = txtIntake.Text
NewPatient.Offset(0, 4).Value = txtLastppointment.Text
NewPatient.Offset(0, 5).Value = txtFollowup.Text
1 stDisplay.ColumnCount = 10
1 stDisplay.RowSource = "A1:J65356"
```

I expect this code to help me add new information into a data entry but I received the error 424 object required.

Comment: `1 stDisplay` What is this?

Comment: I use it in order for the data to input into the registry.

Comment: What line specifically gives the error?

Comment: @Cyril The lines that give me the error are these: NewPatient.Offset(0, 0).Value = txtPatientID.Text.

Comment: So you want `NewPatient.value = txtPatientID.Text` ?  have you attempted that, without using offset and no offset coordinates?

Comment: @cyril Yes I have tried it that way as well but I keep getting the same error in those lines.

Comment: @IgnacioRamirez ...did you verify that `txtPatientID` is the NAME of a textbox in the userform?  in running your code, the error I am getting is related to your object for the `.text`.  As soon as I added the name to the textbox it moved to the next line and gave the same error until I named a textbox `txtFirstname`

Comment: @cyril I just tested this and I still received the same error. Do you perhaps know another method that would add new information into a database?

Comment: @cyril Thank you I had to delete the dimensions and I also deleted the text boxes and created new ones again with the names assigned. The code is working properly now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text box names are your problem.

Ensure the names are assigned so they show up in the properties:

[image]

In running your code (with commenting out the last 2 lines, as noted), i get an error on the above created userform where i do not have a textbox named that:

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim NewPatient As Range
    Set wks = Sheet1
    Set NewPatient = wks.Range("A65356").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    NewPatient.Offset(0, 0).Value = txtPatientID.Text
    NewPatient.Offset(0, 1).Value = txtFirstname.Text
    NewPatient.Offset(0, 2).Value = txtLastname.Text  'ERROR LINE FOR ME
    NewPatient.Offset(0, 3).Value = txtIntake.Text
    NewPatient.Offset(0, 4).Value = txtLastppointment.Text
    NewPatient.Offset(0, 5).Value = txtFollowup.Text
    'commenting out the 1 sections as they are giving me an unrelated issue
'1     stDisplay.ColumnCount = 10
'1     stDisplay.RowSource = "A1:J65356"
End Sub
```

The error message is:

[image]